# Support for non-Latin characters in headless Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, unicode, cjk, google-chrome-headless

I'm having difficulty getting headless Chrome to display non-Latin characters correctly, specifically Chinese characters.

I'm running Chrome 61.x in headless mode on Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed several fonts that should support Chinese characters, including GNU FreeFont and Google's Noto font. I have `fontconfig` installed and have tried rebuilding the cache after installing fonts (using both the `sudo fc-cache -f -v` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig` commands) and restarting the `google-chrome` process to no avail. I also tried upgrading to the latest version of Chrome (65.x) but this did not resolve the issue either nor did disabling GPU acceleration in Chrome (GPU acceleration was tied to problems in earlier versions).

I've done a lot of searching on Google, have stopped finding new advice, and so wonder if there is anything else I can try that hasn't been suggested yet.

Comment: I've been experiencing some problems with this as well. Some extended unicode characters are being replaced with "??". I'm running on Windows server so I'm thinking it's a headless Chrome problem.

Comment: I have the same issue on AWS with the headless-chrome installed by puppeteer. Tried several solutions, mostly boiling down to installing extra fonts. I might have found a solution for your Ubuntu version [here](https://superuser.com/questions/736822/what-is-wrong-with-korean-displaying-on-the-browser), but has anyone already found a general solution maybe?

Comment: Nevermind on AWS EC2 installing the "Korean Support" and other support fonts from CentOS solved it for me
```sh
    #! /bin/bash

    # Install support for Asian characters from CentOS repo
    sudo echo "[centos]
    name=CentOS \$releasever - \$basearch
    baseurl=http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/centos/6/os/\$basearch/
    enabled=1
    pgcheck=0" > /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo

    sudo yum -y --skip-broken  groupinstall "Korean Support" "Chinese Support" "Japanese Support"
```